# Custom Control in iPhone Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

This appears to be a common question, but I haven't seen it answered clearly or succinctly - and as such I'm having trouble making it work.

I have created a Widget.xib file in Interface Builder. It consists of:

```
View (UIView)
  ImageView (UIImageView)
  Button (UIButton)
  Label (UILabel)
```

I have created Widget.h and Widget.m, which implement class Widget, which derives from UIView. In Interface Builder, Widget.xib has its File's Owner set to the Widget class.

Widget.h looks like this:

```
@interface IconView : UIView {
IBOutlet UIButton *widgetButton;
IBOutlet UILabel *widgetLabel;
IBOutlet UIView *widgetView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *widgetImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *widgetButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *widgetLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *widgetView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *widgetImage;
```

Widget.h includes:

```
@synthesize widgetButton, widgetLabel, widgetView, widgetImage;
```

And its dealloc releases those four objects. In Interface Builder, the button, label, view, and imageview are all connected to the appropriate IBOutlets.

Back in Interface Builder, I've opened another XIB from the project. This is Playfield.xib. It's a more traditional view, backed with PlayfieldViewController.h and .m. It contains:

```
View (UIView)
  ImageView (with a static graphic) (UIImageView)
  Button (UIButton)
  Widget
  Widget
  Widget
```

In Playfield.h, I've created IBOutlets for the button and the three Widgets.

```
@interface LinkViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIButton *buttonBack;
IBOutlet Widget *widget0;
IBOutlet Widget *widget1;
IBOutlet Widget *widget2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Widget *widget0;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Widget *widget1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Widget *widget2;
- (IBAction)buttonBackClicked:(id)sender;
```

These are also synthesized and released in Playfield.h. In Interface Builder, Playfield.xib shows three empty rectangles where the widgets have been placed, which is what I expected. Those are wired up to their corresponding IBOutlets in Playfield.h.

So, at this point I assume everything is ready to go. In Playfield.m's viewDidLoad, I do this:

self.widget0.label.text = @"Feed Me";

In my mind, that references the widget0 IBOutlet declared in Playfield.h. That connects to the first Widget item in Playfield.xib. That, in turn, has a declared label IBOutlet in Widget.xib and Widget.h. A UILabel has a Text property. So it should change the text on the label within the widget.

But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

(I want to emphasize that I'm not looking to make an Interface Builder plugin. I know those are complicated. Within IB, I'm fine manipulating my Widgets as empty rectangles. I'll also note that I've set the background color for the widget's View, in Widget.xib, to white. When I run the project, I can clearly see the white rectangles atop the playfield graphic, so I know the widgets are "in" there. I just can't seem to access them.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions... ultimately, I decided to discard this approach. It was creating a lot of wonkiness with object retention and memory, and since the widget is so simple (it's a UILabel and a UIImageView), it was easier just to add those items programmatically than to make a custom class for it all.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you call the `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method to load your Widget subviews from your Widget.XIB?

Also you did connect your views in your Widget.XIB file to the File's Owner (which is a Widget object) so the IBOutlets are connected and give you access to the views… but did you add the views as a subview to your Widgets?

Is the outlet nil when you try to access it using `self.widget0.label` ? Check if `self.widget0` is not `nil` (I guess for that it is OK) but also if `self.widget0.label` is not `nil` too (I guess that's the real the problem). If it is, you probably forgot to load your Widget.xib for each widget view. If it isn't, then it probably means that you have your label, but it isn't added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Uh, I didn't. In Playfield.xib, I went to the Classes tab in the IB toolbox and dragged the Widget class in manually. I did connect the UIView in Widget.xib to an IBOutlet UIView in File's Owner... but I didn't do anything programmatic to add subviews. 

See, I think I need a bit more of a walkthrough on how to do this. All the Q&A here (and everywhere else I've found) are fragmentary and don't cover the entire process.

Comment: The fact that tour class is named Widget and you have a Widget.XIB is not sufficient. When you have a MyViewController.xib, you often precise to use this XIB either in IB by setting the XIB File Name in the inspector (because ViewControllers expose such a property to IB), or when creating your VC by code, using `initWithNibNamed:bundle:` which does take the XIB name (and use it internally to perform a `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` when needed). [...]

Comment: [...] So for your widget, you also need to tell (by code) which XIB to load. The `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method (to be called on `[NSBundle mainBundle]`) will load the XIB, and thus will instantiate the views you created in the XIB, and then connect the outlets, including the ones connected to the XIB's "File's Owner" (which is your Widget object passed as the `owner:` parameter). Once you have called this method, your IBOutlets will point to the instances created by loading the NIB, but you still need to add the main view as a subview of your Widget.

Comment: Note that once you have understood how all of this works, you can move the code in the `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` methods of the Widget class; That way, the loading of the Widget.XIB (and the work to add the view as a subview of the widget) will be done each time a new widget is instantiated - by code using ìnitWithFrame:` explicitly, or when created from a XIB like from Playfield.XIB and `initWithCoder:` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of your XIB setup doesn’t mention the `label` outlet on Widget being actually connected to its label in the XIB. Check that, maybe? It sounds as if you’ve got everything else set up, though you don’t need to declare the `IBOutlet` attribute on the instance variable, just the property.

Comment: within Widget.xib, the UILabel is connected to File's Owner (which is the Widget class, a descendent of UIView), to the label IBOutlet.

Comment: Okay, that isn’t it, then. Set a breakpoint on the line where you try to set the label’s text, then try things like `po [self widget0]`, `po [[self widget0] label]`, etc., and make sure that all of the objects are actually set.

Answer (score 0):

A common one I often miss is setting the class type to widget in IB.

[image: A screenshot of Widget Class Selected in IB]

Comment: So the class AND the File's Owner should be Widget?